# Turn of LAN Controller on Raspberry Pi 4 for power savings

Tags: pi-4, power, ethernet

I have a need for two UART ports with ~115200 bps capability without using the USB port due to which I'm forced to use the Raspberry Pi 4 with its multiple UARTs. My other problem is I'm trying to save power for which I was hoping to be able to turn off the USB/LAN controller altogether. This used to work neatly using hub-ctrl on the 3B+ and there was a huge saving in power by turning off the chip. On the Pi4, I've managed to find uhubctl to turn off the USB hub, but that doesn't really save me any power and I can't find a way to turn off the LAN controller entirely to save more power. Does anyone have thoughts on how I can do this?

Thanks!

Siddharth

Comment: Why not use a lower powered Pi and a serial port HAT and off-load the TX / RX work to hardware?

Comment: An option is to use a serial expander hat with the Pi3 but I've so far been unsuccessful in finding a good solution. Space is a consideration for me - I cannot use a DB09 connector on the expander because of space issues. Any suggestions for expanders?

Comment: Google turned up https://shop.sb-components.co.uk/collections/raspberry-pi-hats/products/serial-expansion-hat-for-raspberry-pi Not used one though

Comment: Thanks! Are these generally reliable? The one thing I've seen is that I haven't found these ever being retailed widely at places like Digikey/Sparkfun/Adafruit etc so it always strikes me as a little bit dodgy...maybe it shouldn't...